# Resource does not show the id of new components or layouts added in the project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

i created a new project in Xamarin, but when I add a new layout it does not appear in Resource.Id, already re-compiled the application, restarted the Xamarin (and even rsrsr pc). In Resource.designer.cs file within the class Layout not appear the new componetes:

```
public partial class Layout
    {

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f030000
        public const int actionbar = 2130903040;

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f030001
        public const int actionbar_item = 2130903041;

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f030002
        public const int blankspinner = 2130903042;

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f030003
        public const int Main = 2130903043;

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f030004
        public const int overflowactionbar_item = 2130903044;

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f030005
        public const int spinneritem = 2130903045;

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f030006
        public const int tabs = 2130903046;

        static Layout()
        {
            global::Android.Runtime.ResourceIdManager.UpdateIdValues();
        }

        private Layout()
        {
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You could try some of the solutions in this SO questions:

Comment: Sometimes it helps to delete stuff inside the Resource.Designer.cs file, sometimes it helps to create a new AXML file. Recently the re-creation of the Resource.Designer.cs file has been spotty :-/

Comment: Check the `BuildAction` of new added file it should be `AndroidResource`. You can find it in the properties of the file

Comment: Tnks for reply, the solution i found was to add the id without even exist and compile the code with this all other ids appeared.